# Android: default locale language "hd"

Tags: android, locale

I used Locale.getDefault.getDisplayLanauge() to get language code, but I get "hd". I don't know what's it. I suppose it should be "en".

Could someone give me a hint why it's "hd" by default, and what does it mean?

Comment: What phone is this? I don't think hd is a valid language code. What does getLanguage() return?

Comment: Weird, there seems to be no "hd" language code according to [ISO 639-1](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Are you making your own Android build?

It's happening, when you use the screen density as first argument of PRODUCT_LOCALES. In my product mk file the first argument of PRODUCT_LOCALES was hdpi. I moved it to the end and now everything is working fine. 
You probably have the exact same problem as I had. The Android build process takes the first two letters of the first word in PRODUCT_LOCALES and stores them as default language. And if you have, like I had, hdpi Android takes "hd" as default language!

Also I found this comment in a Android makefile, which explains this problem perfectly:

Screen density is actually considered a locale (since it is taken into account
the the build-time selection of resources). The product definitions including
this file must pay attention to the fact that the first entry in the final
PRODUCT_LOCALES expansion must not be a density.

Comment: That's it. I have fixed the problem several weeks ago, thanks for your explanation.